# Тернарный оператор вместо конструкции if-else

Tags: java, if

Можно ли улучшить(упростить) данную конструкцию тернарным оператором?

```
if (isLeftLetter && isRightLetter) {
    swap(chars, leftElementIndex, rightElementIndex);
    leftElementIndex++;
    rightElementIndex--;

} else {         
    if (!isLeftLetter) {
        leftElementIndex++;
    }

    if (!isRightLetter) {
        rightElementIndex--;
    }
}
```

Comment: При таких больших конструкциях тернарный оператор условия нежелательно использовать. Он лишь ухудшит читаемость кода, а не упростит.

Comment: а если часть заменить? И вообще это реально сделать?

Comment: @АнтонЛуценко Как вам верно подсказали, тернарный оператор превратит ваши условия в кашу. Но, возможно, сами условия можно оптимизировать. Сложно тут что-то сказать без контекста. Для этого вам нужно добавить в вопрос, что вы пытаетесь сделать, какую задачу решить и.т.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы написал так:

```
if (isLeftLetter && isRightLetter) {
    swap(chars, leftElementIndex, rightElementIndex);
    leftElementIndex++;
    rightElementIndex--;

} else {
    leftElementIndex=(!isLeftLetter) ? leftElementIndex+1 : leftElementIdex;
    rightElementIndex=(!isRightLetter) ? rightElementIndex+1 : rightElementIdex;
}
```

**Update**

Тернарный оператор удобно использовать для однострочных присвоений, а ля:

```
var=(condition) ? expression1 : expression2;
```

в остальных вариантах, я лично не рекомендую (верю, что некоторые не согласятся)

Comment: можно ещё так: `leftElementIndex += isLeftLetter ? 0 : 1;`

Answer (score 3):

```
(isLeftLetter && isRightLetter) ?
    (swap(chars, leftElementIndex, rightElementIndex), leftElementIndex++, rightElementIndex--) :
    (
        (!isLeftLetter) ? leftElementIndex++ : leftElementIndex,
        (!isRightLetter) ? rightElementIndex-- : rightElementIndex
    );
```

Все же нежелательно использовать данную конструкцию. Как видите читаемость стала лишь сложнее. Но если это Ваш личный проект и Вы сами его поймете, то дело Ваше.

Comment: Такой код Ок для матерых Си-шников, но для Java слишком :)

Comment: Я учусь пока, поэтому пробую по разному

Comment: @АнтонЛуценко так вот так лучше даже не пробуйте.