# Тернарный оператор вместо конструкции if-else (2)

Tags: java, if

Задался вот [этим вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/779128/190461).*(там тоже самое ввиде ответа удалю)*

Просто интересно. Есть ощущение что я не прав, не могу уловить где.

Первая часть условия

```
swap(chars, leftElementIndex, rightElementIndex);
leftElementIndex++;
rightElementIndex--;
```

выполнится, если

```
isLeftLetter && isRightLetter
```

есть

```
true && true
```

Вторая часть условия

```
if (!isLeftLetter) {
    leftElementIndex++;
}

if (!isRightLetter) {
    rightElementIndex--;
}
```

выполнится если

```
isLeftLetter && isRightLetter
```

есть сочетания

```
true && false
false && true
false && false
```

Во второй части `isLeftLetter` и `isRightLetter` переворачиваются

```
false <- !true <-     true && false    -> !false -> true
true <- !false <-     false && true    -> !true -> false
true <- !false <-     false && false   -> !false -> true
```

Выходит, что во второй части условия

```
leftElementIndex++;
rightElementIndex--;
```

выполняются независимо от того

```
isLeftLetter  - true или false
isRightLetter  - true или false
```

значит все условие можно свести к

```
if (isLeftLetter && isRightLetter) {
    swap(chars, leftElementIndex, rightElementIndex);
    leftElementIndex++;
    rightElementIndex--;

} else {         
    leftElementIndex++;
    rightElementIndex--;
}
```

тогда зачем повторяться? может так? Поправьте меня пжл если выводы мои неправильны.

```
if (isLeftLetter && isRightLetter) {
    swap(chars, leftElementIndex, rightElementIndex);
}
    leftElementIndex++;
    rightElementIndex--;
```

Comment: >> тогда зачем повторяться? << Вывод верный, общий код легко выносится за `if` что вы и сделали. Отчего сомневаетесь в своих выводах?

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин: сомневаюсь в корректности равносильного сведе(')ния первоначального кода к последнему виду. То есть, верны ли рассуждения?

Comment: Ситуация: isLeftLetter = true; isRightLetter = false; В исходной проверке leftElementIndex++; - не выполнится, в вашем выполнится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наглядно:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    boolean a = (i & 1) == 1;
    boolean b = (i & 2) == 2;
    System.out.println("a = " + a + ", b = " + b);
    if (a && b) {
        System.out.println("Run a && b");
    } else {
        if (!a) {
            System.out.println("Run !a");
        }
        if (!b) {
            System.out.println("Run !b");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Результат:

```
a = false, b = false
Run !a
Run !b

a = true, b = false
Run !b

a = false, b = true
Run !a

a = true, b = true
Run a && b
```

Comment: весьма наглядно, благодарю.